# C# Task.WhenAll not triggering next task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to multi-tasking, however I'm trying to learn how it all works.  I have the following code, which I thought would create a task and run the performInitialLoad method, and when that completes, would then fire off the initializeDataHarvester method.  The performInitialLoad works fine, and it does reach the bottom of the method because I can see the text "Initial tag data load complete" in my console.  But it never seems to fire the initializeDataHarvester method.  Any ideas?

```
private void mainTaskLoader() {
     Task initialLoad = new Task(performInitialTagLoad);
     initialLoad.Start();
     Task dataHarvester = new Task(() => {
          Task.WhenAll(initialLoad);
     }).ContinueWith(t => initializeDataHarvester());         
}

private void performInitialTagLoad() {
   allTags = globals.getTags();
   foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> tag in allTags) {
       try {
           globals.insertUpdateHarvesterData(tag.Key.ToString(), commObject.Read(tag.Value.ToString()));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           Console.WriteLine("Error on initial load: " + e.Message, true);                    
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Initial tag data load complete");         
}

private void initializeDataHarvester() {
        Console.WriteLine("Got here!");            
}
```

Comment: When your dataHarvester task being started?

Comment: This is why you never use the task constructor; use `Task.Run` to create a task that represents a delegate run in a thread pool thread.

Comment: @skalinkin, I'm not calling start on it because I thought that's what the ContinueWith method was for, once the initialLoad task completed it would  start the dataHarvester task?  That not correct?

Comment: @Phil: No, `ContinueWith` says what to do when the task has completed - but it's never going to complete if you don't start it. Not that that second task does what you want anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` returns immediately - but it returns a *task* which will complete when the tasks have completed. You're ignoring that return value at the moment. You're also not starting the task which calls `WhenAll`, which is why that task is never completing.

You could just use:

```
Task.WhenAll(initialLoad).ContinueWith(...);
```

... but better yet, you could just avoid using `WhenAll` at all, given that you've only got a single task anyway.

You should also:

- Learn about async/await, which makes a lot of things *much* easier
- Start following .NET naming conventions

With async/await, this code would be something like:

```
private async Task MainTaskLoader()
{
    await Task.Run(PerformInitialTagLoad);
    InitializeDataHarvester();
}
```

If you genuinely have multiple things to run, you could use:

```
private async Task MainTaskLoader()
{
    var task1 = Task.Run(PerformInitialTagLoad);
    var task2 = Task.Run(SomethingElse);
    // Imagine we have many of these...
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    InitializeDataHarvester();
}
```

Ideally, you'd make `PerformInitialTagLoad` an async method as well, mind you - which would require making the insertion async too.

Comment: how would I go about making the performInitialTagLoad method async?  I tried changing it to private async Task performInitialTagLoad() but that throws a warning that I'm not using await...

Comment: @Phil: Well presumably `insertUpdateHarvesterData` is the slow part - so *that* would need to be async too, and you could await each insert (or possibly do them in parallel). But I'd get it all working first :)